# Unable to convert a string to an integer variable from DateTaken attribute on a JPG file

Tags: powershell

I have a script which is using the EXIF data from a JPG file to find the `DateTaken` value. Once found, place the data in `$Year` and `$Month` variables.

```
$objShell  = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$folders = (Get-ChildItem G:\ServerFolders\Photos\UnSorted\ -Directory -Recurse -force).FullName

foreach ($Folder in $folders) {
    $objfolder = $objShell.Namespace($folder)

    foreach ($file in $objFolder.Items()) {
        if ($objfolder.GetDetailsOf($file, 156) -eq ".jpg") {
            $yeartaken = ($objFolder.GetDetailsOf($File, 12)).Split("/")[2].Split(" ")[0]
            $month = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($File, 12).Split("/")[1]
            $monthname = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($month)

            Write-Host $file.Name
        }
    }
}
```

So, if the file has a DateTaken as 06/10/2016, `$yeartaken` is `2016` and `$month` is `10`

I then to `Get-Culture` to convert the 10 into October. This doesn't work because it's seeing `$month` as a string.

```
Cannot convert argument "month", with value: "‎10", for "GetMonthName" to
type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value "‎10" to type "System.Int32".
Error: "Input string was not in a correct format.""
At line:1 char:3
+   (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($month)
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument
```

I've tried to convert it to a Integer value using casting or converting, but for some reason it won't convert.

```
PS> [int]$Test = $month

Cannot convert value "‎10" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was
not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:1
+ [int]$Test = $month
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Comment: Thanks to mklement0's answer. It was indeed hidden characters being returned.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to working with dates is to convert the date string to an actual `DateTime` object, which provides all the information you're looking for:

```
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$pattern = 'dd\/MM\/yyyy'

$datestring = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($File, 12).Split(' ')[0]
$datetaken  = [DateTime]::ParseExact($datestring, $pattern, $culture)

$year      = $datetaken.Year
$month     = $datetaken.Month              # month (numeric)
$monthname = $datetaken.ToString('MMMM')   # month name
```

Assuming that the date is followed by a time in the format `HH:mm:ss` you could extend the code to handle the time as well:

```
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$pattern = 'dd\/MM\/yyyy HH:mm:ss'

$datestring = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($File, 12)
$timestamp  = [DateTime]::ParseExact($datestring, $pattern, $culture)

$year      = $timestamp.Year
$month     = $timestamp.Month              # month (numeric)
$monthname = $timestamp.ToString('MMMM')   # month name
$hour      = $timestamp.Hour
...
```

Comment: Note: This answer shows helpful date-string-parsing techniques, but doesn't address the primary problem: the presence of invisible control characters in the string returned by `.GetDetailsOf()`, which must be removed.

Answer (score 1):

**The date-and-time string returned by `$objFolder.GetDetailsOf($File, 12)` contains *invisible control characters***.

You can **strip them** as follows, after which your code should work:

```bash
# Remove the formatting control characters from the string.
$dateTimeStr = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($File, 12) -replace '\p{Cf}'

# Note: The date format shown is directly recognized by 
#       PowerShell's [datetime] casts, which use the invariant culture.
$dateTaken = [datetime] $dateTimeStr
$monthname = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($dateTaken.Month)
```

`\p{Cf}` matches characters in the [`Format` Unicode category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory), which comprises any character that "affects the layout of text or the operation of text processes, but is not normally rendered."

Specifically, in my test file's metadata I found *multiple* instances of Unicode control characters [U+200E (LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) and [U+200F (RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm).

As for *why* these invisible control characters are present (information from [this forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/77554c16-3050-448d-8455-b0aab3f6b2f4/datetaken-extended-file-attribute-returned-from-getdetailsof-method-has-embedded-whitespace?forum=vbgeneral), courtesy of [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton)):

> The characters that you are seeing (along with some others, such as nulls) are embedded in BSTRs to allow the calling function to correctly display the string for any locale.  It includes such things as the left to right marker that you saw, so that the calling application knows that the characters must be grouped and displayed left to right.

However, it's not quite clear why an explicit direction marker is needed for the *default* direction, left-to-right, and why seemingly *each date component* is preceded by one, and the time component even by *two*; here's an example of what *should* just be date string `9/5/2015 11:32 AM`, with the invisible control characters visualized as PowerShell (Core) 7+ Unicode escape sequences (via [`Debug-String`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/7f2f1e13ac9c2afaf0a0906d08b392d1)):

```
`u{200e}9/`u{200e}5/`u{200e}2015·`u{200f}`u{200e}11:32·AM
```

As an aside, on a general note: [Ansgar Wiecher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52593756/45375) shows more robust date-time string parsing techniques.

---

**Self-contained sample**:

The following example extracts the "Date Taken" field from file `test.jpg` located in the current folder and converts it to a `[datetime]` instance - note the need to use `.ParseName()` in order to pass an object representing the target file that the `.GetDetailsOf()` method understands:

```bash
[datetime] (
  ($folder = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).
    Namespace($PWD.ProviderPath)).
    GetDetailsOf($folder.ParseName('test.jpg'), 12) -replace '\p{Cf}'
)
```